# Sublime Text 3: How to jump to the parent/enclosing function?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Is there a quick keyboard shortcut or Command Palette function to quickly jump to the parent/enclosing function?

So if the cursor is in a function, then I want to quickly jump to the first line of that function.

I looked around but was unable to find such a shortcut.

Answer (score 8):

## Jump to matching brackets is easy!

Stand on some braces(brackets, parentheses) and press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>(Mac <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).

## File members

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>(Mac <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) to see list of file members(variables, functions, methods, etc...)

Comment: `Ctrl`+`R`(Mac `⌘`+`R`) was very helpful for me - I came across this post trying to find a way to see the current "scope" of where my cursor was (ie the containing function). 
 This allowed me to do that and then press `Esc` to get back to the cursor position.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, press `CONTROL + R` which lists all the functions in the file with the current function selected. Now, Press `ENTER`

Answer (score 0):

[Sublime Move By Symbols](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Move%20By%20Symbols) allows you to navigate between symbols, so if your cursor is inside a function, then ctrl+up will move it to the function name.